# How to use map on Object in stencil

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

In index.html data is passed to stencil component

```
<app-root
      data="{abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com}"
</app-root>
```

**App-root stencil Component**

```
import { Component, h, Prop } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: "app-root",
  styleUrl: "app-root.css",
  shadow: true,
})
export class AppRoot {
  @Prop() data: [];
  
  render() {
  return (
      <div>
        {this.data.map(m=>{
        return  <div>
          <h1>{m}</h1>     
          </div>  
        }   
       </div>
  }
}
```

How to get single data inside h1 tag, while using this way it shows undefined on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `<app-root>` in an HTML file (not TSX) you can only pass primitive types (`string`, `number`, `boolean`). If you want to pass an array you will have to manually parse it, see [Stencil object properties are not set, when they provided through the HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670562/1242317).

Then the attribute value should be a valid JSON array (`["abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com"]`)

In your case instead of `JSON.parse` you could also pass a comma separated list and create an array with `split(',')`, in which case the attribute value should be `abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set non-primitives as property values in HTML. You can set them via JavaScript though:

```html
<app-root></app-root>

<script>
  document.querySelector('app-root').data = ['abc@gmail.com', 'def@gmail.com'];
</script>
```

Note that `{abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com}` is not a valid array in JavaScript/Typescript. You should also assign an empty array as a default value to your `data` prop, so that it doesn't fail to render if `data` is unset (which is why you're seeing "undefined" on the screen).

```
@Prop() data = [];
```

If you want to improve the type of your prop, you can define it as a string array by doing

```
@Prop() data: string[] = [];
```